# C++ undefined reference to `Vector_container::Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double>)'

Tags: c++, compilation, abstract-class

I'm trying to compile the code from *A Tour of C++*, Chapter 4.3, which describes "Abstract Types". However, I am getting a compiler error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 abstract.cpp Vector.cpp Vector_container.cpp
/tmp/ccToFsNS.o: In function `g()':
abstract.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `Vector_container::Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double>)'
abstract.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `Vector_container::~Vector_container()'
abstract.cpp:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `Vector_container::~Vector_container()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix my code so it compiles? I am brand new to C++ and am trying to transcribe Stroustrup's examples to the best of my ability.

abstract.cpp:

```
#include "Vector_container.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void use(Container& c)
{
  const int sz = c.size();
  for (auto i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << c[i] << "\n";
    }
}

void g()
{
  Vector_container vc {10, 9, 8, 7, 6};
  use(vc);
}

int main()
{
  g();
}
```

Vector_container.hpp:

```
#include "Container.hpp"
#include "Vector.hpp"
#include <initializer_list>

#pragma once

class Vector_container : public Container {
  Vector v;
public:
  Vector_container(int);
  Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double>);
  ~Vector_container();
  double& operator[](int);
  int size() const;
};
```

Vector_container.cpp:

```
#include "Container.hpp"
#include "Vector.hpp"

class Vector_container : public Container {
  Vector v;
public:
  Vector_container(int s) : v(s) {}
  Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double> lst) : v{lst} {}
  ~Vector_container() {}
  double& operator[](int i) { return v[i]; }
  int size() const { return v.size(); }
};
```

container.hpp:

```
#pragma once

class Container {
public:
  virtual double& operator[](int) = 0;
  virtual int size() const = 0;
  virtual ~Container() {}
};
```

Vector.hpp:

```
#include <initializer_list>

#pragma once

class Vector {
public:
  Vector(int);
  Vector(std::initializer_list<double>);
  ~Vector();
  double& operator[](int);
  int size() const;
  void push_back(double);
private:
  double* elem;
  int sz;
};
```

Vector.cpp:

```
#include "Vector.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>

Vector::Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s}
{
  if (s < 0)
    {
      throw std::length_error{"Size must be >= 0"};
    }
  for (auto i = 0; i != s; ++i)
    {
      elem[i] = 0;
    }
}

Vector::Vector(std::initializer_list<double> lst)
  : elem{new double[lst.size()]}, sz{static_cast<int>(lst.size())}
    {
      std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
    }

Vector::~Vector() {
  delete[] elem;
}

double& Vector::operator[](int i)
{
  if (i < 0 || size() <= i)
    {
      throw std::out_of_range{"Vector::operator[]"};
    }
  return elem[i];
}

int Vector::size() const
{
  return sz;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `class Vector_container` declarations - one containing declarations, other definitions?

Comment: Right now you're defining `Vector_container` _twice_. The contents of the .cpp should be in the .hpp.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by commenters and Sam, I was not defining `Vector_container` correctly. I changed Vector_container.cpp to:

```
#include "Vector_container.hpp"

Vector_container::Vector_container(int s) : v(s) {}
Vector_container::Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double> lst) : v{lst} {}
Vector_container::~Vector_container() {}

double& Vector_container::operator[](int i)
{
  return v[i];
}
int Vector_container::size() const
{
  return v.size();
}
```

And now the program compiles and runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read that particular book, but I would be surprised to learn that Stroustrup would write something that:

1) Explicitly depends on gcc-specific pragmas, and

2) Encourage the abuse of `#pragma once`

3) Offers an example of this kind of bad practice of declaring a class in the header file, but then define the class's methods in a completely separate translation unit that does not even include the header file.

Just get rid of your `Vector_container.hpp` entirely, then rename `Vector_container.cpp` to `Vector_container.hpp`, and the code should compile and link just fine.

Your problem is that nothing in the existing `Vector_container.cpp` translation unit actually ends up instantiating and compiling the class methods, in order for the linker to find and resolve the references from your other translation units.

You could also replace the inline definitions in `Vector_container.cpp` with non-inline definitions. This will also instantiate them. But this won't do anything about the duplicate definition in `Vector_container.hpp`, which I think is very bad practice.

Comment: I think the issue was that I wrote the header first, then lazily copied it into my .cpp file and tried to define the methods then. But that resulted in a duplicate definition.

Comment: `#pragma once` was not suggested by Stroustrup but was my own addition to prevent compiler errors if I happened to include the same header in multiple files. Are you suggesting I should use `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif` instead?

Comment: The #ifndef/#define/#endif is, indeed, the typical approach that's pretty much used by every software library.